# Three.js camera, object and scene origin when moving object

Tags: object, camera, three.js, reset, scene

I can not figure out how to set the object to the three.js scene origin after having moved it. What happens is that I built a scene with an object at the origin and a camera pointing at it.
I am using the mouse to move around the object in the scene.
Then I try to reset the object position so that it goes back to the scene origin like that with the camera pointed at it:

```
camera.position.x = 10;
camera.position.y = 10;
camera.position.z = 10;
camera.lookAt( scene.position );
group.position.set(0, 0, 0);
```

I seems fine at first. But when I try to rotate the camera with the mouse around the object, the object shifts back to its previous position and the camera is not centered around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using controls. Just do this:

```
controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 );
```